# Is it possible to pre-install tools such as .net core sdk, etc on ms-hosted agents in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to pre-install tools such as .net core sdk, etc on ms-hosted agents in azure devops instead of having the installation of tools as part of the build job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will link to Microsoft resources here, only because it really is the official word on such things.

If you go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software, and then find the VM Image you're using, there will be a link to a Github page that lists in detail every component and version installed on that image. In the case of your question (.NET Core SDK), they install the following versions under C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk:

> 2.1.300 2.1.301 2.1.302 2.1.401 2.1.402 2.1.403 2.1.500 2.1.502 2.1.503 2.1.504 2.1.505 2.1.506 2.1.507 2.1.508 2.1.509 2.1.510 2.1.511 2.1.512 2.1.513 2.1.514 2.1.515 2.1.516 2.1.517 2.1.518 2.1.519 2.1.520 2.1.521 2.1.602 2.1.603 2.1.604 2.1.605 2.1.606 2.1.607 2.1.608 2.1.609 2.1.610 2.1.611 2.1.612 2.1.613 2.1.614 2.1.615 2.1.616 2.1.617 2.1.700 2.1.701 2.1.801 2.1.802 2.1.803 2.1.804 2.1.805 2.1.806 2.1.807 2.1.808 2.1.809 2.1.810 2.1.811 2.1.812 2.1.813 3.1.100 3.1.101 3.1.102 3.1.103 3.1.104 3.1.105 3.1.106 3.1.107 3.1.108 3.1.109 3.1.110 3.1.111 3.1.112 3.1.200 3.1.201 3.1.202 3.1.300 3.1.301 3.1.302 3.1.401 3.1.402 3.1.403 3.1.404 3.1.405 3.1.406 5.0.100 5.0.101 5.0.102 5.0.103

Can *you* pre-install tools on a MS-hosted image? No, but you can request that components be added to the image by opening an issue at https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments.